# Show actual rw status of NFS mount from client

Tags: linux, permissions, nfs, mount

If a directory is exported by a Linux NFS server as `ro` but mounted on a Linux client with the option `rw` how can I check the effective permissions, i.e. as dictated by the export, when I'm on the client?

Answer (score 0):

A direct way to get this information doesn't exist. As a workaround, you can try to create a file in the nfs mount. You should get **EROFS** or **EACCES** error, which may indicated a ro export.

```
$ mount -t nfs4
  srv:/ on /net/dsrv type nfs4 (rw,nosuid,....)
$ 

$ python -c 'f = open("testfile", "w")'      
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'testfile'
$
```

The error number **13** is **EACCES**

However, this behavior is NFS server implementation specific and not 100% reliable.

Comment: If I were going to test by creating a file, I would probably just do```$ touch tmpfile``` which gives the error ```touch: cannot touch ‘tmpfile’: Read-only file system```, which is potentially less misleading than ```Permission denied```.